# Multiple DBContext implemented with same Interface

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to register multiple(2) `DbContexts` implemented with a common interface(`IDbContext`). Then I want in my controller some logic to decide which context I'll use.

I'm injecting `IEnumerable<IDbContext>` in `HomeController` but it is resolving with only the first instance that I registered.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(context => { context.UseInMemoryDatabase("ConferencePlanner");});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, Application2DbContext>(context => { context.UseInMemoryDatabase("ConferencePlanner2");});
```

DBContext1

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options){}
}
```

DbContext2

```
public class Application2DbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public Application2DbContext(DbContextOptions<Application2DbContext> options): base(options){}
}
```

IDbContext

```
public interface IDbContext {}
```

Controller:

```
 private readonly IEnumerable<IDbContext> contexts;

 public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IEnumerable<IDbContext> contexts)
 {
     _logger = logger;
     this.contexts = contexts;
 }
```

[image]
I was expecting here both `DbContexts`
I've seen like this approach works if I have multiple repos/services with common interface.

Comment: I think you should pass IEnumerable in sturtup.cs  too. I mean :
`builder.Services.AddDbContext<IEnumerable<IDbContext>, List<DbContext>>(YOUR_IMPLEMENTATION)` or put 2 contexts in your controller constructor I mean :
`HomeController(IDbContext contexts1 , IDbContext> contexts2)`

Comment: `AddDbContex`t not have any overload like your example. It has like this 
`public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContextService, TContextImplementation>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>? optionsAction = null, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped) where TContextImplementation : DbContext, TContextService;` as it's not working

Comment: This sounds like possibly a multi-tenancy design. Consider using a Scoped or Singleton Factory dependency to construct/provide a suitable DbContext based on what the controllers etc. need. (I.e. for relevant tenant)

Comment: Thanks @StevePy, I was just trying it for learning but yes my intent was quite same as multi-tenant(db) app. I dug into AddDbContext source code and found, it internally uses `serviceCollection.TryAdd`, and this only adds service into collection if not already present, that's why I was getting first instance. I suppose method name `TryAddDbContext` would be more informative than `AddDbContext`. But yeah I got my answer Thanks all!.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you're trying to register db contexts using the AddDbContext method. If you try to to register your instances using a factory, it should work as you expect. The code might look like this:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDbContext>(sp => {
  var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
  ...
  context.UseInMemoryDatabase("ConferencePlanner");
  return context;
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IDbContext>(sp => {
  var context = new ApplicationDb2Context();
  ...
  context.UseInMemoryDatabase("ConferencePlanner2");
  return context;
});
```

Then, when you pass IEnumerable to the controller, you would get both instances. However, I would consider using scoped contexts for specific cases so that the controller always use an only instance.